# casperJS contentDocument selector hiddin in #document

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am having trouble clicking a selector in casperJS. If I am not mistaken the selector is hidden in a shadow-root. 
[image: DOM]

```
this.waitForSelector('#tab > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a',function(){
             //yields nothing - timeout   
             });

this.waitForSelector('#tab > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a',x[0].contentDocument,function(){
                console.log("found"); //true
             });
```

where var x is `var x =  this.evaluate(function(){
                        var selected = $('frameset>frame');
                        return selected;
                 });`

When I try and click that. `this.click('#tab > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a',x[0].contentDocument);`nothing happens.

any help would be greatly appreciate it. thanks a lot!